# Searching and Matching a part of a string in a CSV file using Python

Tags: python, string, file, parsing, csv

This is a part of a large csv file which I have:

```
"66.35.223.128","66.35.223.143","1109647232","1109647247","AU","Australia"
"66.35.223.144","66.35.227.191","1109647248","1109648319","US","United States"
"66.35.227.192","66.35.227.207","1109648320","1109648335","JP","Japan"
"66.35.227.208","66.35.230.31","1109648336","1109648927","US","United States"
"66.35.230.32","66.35.230.47","1109648928","1109648943","AU","Australia"
"66.35.230.48","66.35.236.207","1109648944","1109650639","US","United States"
"66.35.236.208","66.35.236.223","1109650640","1109650655","AU","Australia"
"66.35.236.224","66.36.127.255","1109650656","1109688319","US","United States"
```

The first two columns are a range of IP addresses.
I have an IP address 66.35.250.168
I need to search the csv file to see in which range it lies, and print out the corresponding country name.

Since the first two numbers (66,35) are the same, I intend to search for the line containing this.
I can search a complete string(66.35.205.88) by doing this:

```
import csv
with open('GeoIPCountryWhois.csv', mode='r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if row[0] in ['66.35.205.88']:
            print row
```

If I search for 66.35, I don't get any result .
Can you please tell me a way in which I can search for a part of the string ('66.35' here) ?
Also, can you tell me how I can find the exact line number in which I find the string?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Getting the line number is relatively easy. Try changing the fourth line to `for line_number, row in enumerate(reader):`

Comment: Your entire approach to the problem is lacking. What you want to do is parse the entire CSV file to create a data structure, and then work with the data structure. "Line numbers" will be implicit from indices into the list of row-structures. You can use a `namedtuple` to represent each row.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want to do. I wanted the line number just for reference because I had a really large file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import csv
with open('GeoIPCountryWhois.csv', mode='r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for num, row in enumerate(reader):
        if '66.35' in row[0]:
            print num, row
```

Keep in mind this can give you false positives if `'66.35'` appears at other locations in the address or elsewhere in the line.

Edit: Here is a version that can actually check if it's in the right range.

```
def numeric_ip(ip):
    return [int(x) for x in ip.split('.')]

desired_ip = numeric_ip('66.35.205.88')
with open('GeoIPCountryWhois.csv', mode='r') as f:
    for num, row in enumerate(csv.reader(f)):
        if numeric_ip(row[0]) <= desired_ip <= numeric_ip(row[1]):
            print num, row
```

Comment: I just had to change the '<' to '<=' without which I wasn't getting a result.
Thanks a lot! That worked really well.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason `in` shouldn't work.

Make sure you switch the order

```
if '66.35' in row[0]:
    print row
```

Comment: No... that's testing if the _list_ is in row[0]. You need to test if the _string_ is in row[0].

Comment: Yes, row[0] in ['66.35'] works. By switching you mean to search for the list in the string.
I don't get any output if i search for '66.35'

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard boolean tests with strings to check if the ip you're looking for is in the range:

```
import csv

desired_ip = "66.35.232.56"
desired_ip_n = [str(n) for n in desired_ip.split(".")
with open('GeoIPCountryWhois.csv', mode='r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    row_num = 1
    for row in reader:
        ip_start_n = [str(n) for n in row[0].split(".")]
        ip_end_n = [str(n) for n in row[1].split(".")]
        if desired_ip_n >= ip_start_n and desired_ip <= ip_end_n:
            print row
            print row_num
        row_num += 1
```

Comment: I don't think so... it's not numeric ordering so `200` will sort less than `30`.

Comment: yep you're right, I just caught that. But I think you can do a split(".") on the desired ip and the ips defining the range and then compare the resulting lists...